# jumping game with recursion method

Tags: java, recursion

I try to write code to solve jumping game in java the game is if you have array and start index to start the game jump

The start index he is the number you are standing on so you can jump left or right down the line by jumping the number of spaces indicated by the number you are standing on

The goal: you want to get to the 0 at the far end (right side) of the line. You are also guaranteed that there will be only one zero, which, again, will be at the far right side.

So the method return True if I reached to the goal and return False If I did not.

This is the example:

The first number is the start index and the second number is the length of the array and the array is rest of numbers

```
6 8 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0 : True
```

This is my code:

```
public static boolean game(int startindex,int[] array){

    int startgame=array[startindex];

    for(int p=0;p<=10;p++){

        int play=array[0+startgame];

        startgame+=play;

        if(startgame>=array.length){

            startgame-=play;
            startgame-=play;   

        }

        if(array[startgame]==0)
        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
```

when I try this example

3 8 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0 return true

but should return  false because the start index is 3 so I start from his value =6 to  jump either left 6 spaces or right 6 spaces but I could not reached to 0.

and when try this

6 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 0 show Exception

I do not know why.Can anyone help me

Comment: Please correct the punctuation and typing mistakes in your question if you want help from us. I think a minimal amount of respect is due if you need help.

Comment: "I have mistakes and I could not write the code" is not a problem description. *What* mistakes? *Why* can't you write it?

Comment: 3 8 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0 when I  try this give me true and he should return false because I could not reached to 0

Comment: You could print out the path it followed in order to be sure that 3823463520 is actually invalid.

Comment: Why should `3 8 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0` give `false`? You start at 0, jump 3 to the right, land on 3, jump 3 again, land on another 3, jump 3 a third time and you are there.

Comment: 3 8 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0 the start index is 3 so I start from his value 6 and jump either left 6 spaces or right 6 spaces to I reached to 0 but I could not

Comment: Why would you start from 6? 6 is at either the fifth or sixth position, depending on whether you start counting at 0 or 1, but never at the third.

Comment: 3 8 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0 because 3 the start index that I started the game from his value and 8  the length of array and the array is 2 3 4 6 3 5 2 0

Comment: Well, I guess that depends on (a) whether those first two numbers are included in the "start position", and (b) whether the start position should count from 0 or 1.

Comment: the first two numbers just determine the start index and the length of array they not included in array

Answer (score 0):

Since this is obviously homework (not the first time I see this problem) I will only give you pseudocode and some hints on how to solve this.

Your current algorithm does not work properly, as you will (1) only take a maximum of 10 steps, and (2) you will only backtrack if a forwards-jump would be too far. Also, you never check whether a backwards-jump could end outside of the bounds.

Making this a recursive algorithm is very simple: Basically, you just have three cases:

- if the current position is outside of the bounds, return `false`
- if the value at the current position is `0`, return `true`
- otherwise, return whether either the jump to the left or the jump to the right leads to the goal

Also, you may want to remember the "stepping stones" you have already been at, to see whether you are "jumping in circles". In this case, return `false`, too.

Putting it all together, the algorithm could look like this:

```
// inpt: input array, current: current position, seen: list/set of visited positions
boolean function jump(inpt, current, seen):

    if current < 0 or current >= length(inpt) then 
        return false    // jumped too far

    if inpt[current] == 0 then 
        return true     // goal found

    if current in seen then
        return false    // jumping in circles

    return (jump(inpt, current + inpt[current], seen + [current]) 
         or jump(inpt, current - inpt[current], seen + [current]))
```

And call it like `jump([6, 8, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 0], 0, <empty list>)`

Comment: Addendum: Did not see that bit about the first two digits being sort of "meta information", but it should be no problem for you to strip those away. Also, it is not clear from your question whether those should be legal "stepping stones" later in the algorithm and whether the first two digits should be included in the calculation of the start position.